# BING Maps API Lost Geocode

Tags: c#, bing-maps, bing-api

We have a method in C# to get the geocode location for certain addresses.  It works great 99% of the time.  I've ran in to an interesting situation and am hoping someone has ran in to a similar situation.  I haven't been able to find a similar issue on the BING forum or through their development resources.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

Stream data = client.OpenRead(uri);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd();

// Doing some magic with the response object here
```

The URI for this specific situation is:

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q=285%20Annshelia%20Dr,%20Keswick%20ON&key=<LIVEKEY>
```

The response that we are getting from the server is:

```
{"authenticationResultCode":"ValidCredentials","brandLogoUri":"http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png","copyright":"Copyright © 2016 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.","resourceSets":[{"estimatedTotal":0,"resources":[]}],"statusCode":200,"statusDescription":"OK","traceId":"<THE_TRACE>"}
```

There are no HTML headers set for "X-MS-BM-WS-INFO" so it isn't an overload issue and we do have an enterprise key.

The part I'm interested in is how if we go to the [Bing Maps website](https://www.bing.com/maps/) and search for the address of 285 Annshelia Dr, Keswick ON  L4P 3A6, we get a proper geocode location.

Can anyone shed some light on why this would be giving me a blank stare when I ask for the geocodes?

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried to URL Encode the comma in your uri to %2C ? Sometimes adding in a comma can be viewed as a separator in a URL rather than the char.

Comment: Thanks Ryan!  Even with adding in the HttpUtility.UrlEncode(address) in to the String.Format() when making the URI, I'm still getting the same response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been found - it was a spelling mistake on the street name.

Answer (score 3):

I've taken a look into this. The issue is to be expected at this time. The Bing Maps website is currently using a new backend geocoder which has a new data set. This new geocoder is going through quality control testing and the Bing Maps team is using the Bing Maps website as a test site for this new geocoder. The Bing Maps developer API's will be updated on the backend once quality control testing is complete in a few months.

Comment: So there's not much we can do if we're relying on their api for geocode locations?

Comment: It's strange that Bing would be using a development dataset for their live data that is currently in QA.  Thanks so much for looking in to this for us though!  I really appreciate it.

Comment: The dataset isn't a development dataset. It is simply a more up to date dataset. The older geocoder takes several weeks to update with data, where as the new platform can be updated almost instantly. As such the new data is only in the new geocoder. It also helps to verify that majority of past reported issues with the geocoder are now resolved. Just a matter of updating the developer API's to the new geocoder in the next few months.